# Can someone give me a few hints on my geometry homework?

Tags: geometry, triangles

I have to do a worksheet that's about similarity and I've got through all problems but one, which is insanely hard. This is what it's asking, "The side lengths of a triangle are 27, 36, and 42. Each angle bisector intersects the opposite side to form six segments. Find the length of each of these six segments." Here is the diagram: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PESm.jpg

Here's my logic. I start off with a normal triangle with side lengths 27, 36, and 42. I draw in the angle bisectors and now I have 3 pairs of congruent angles. I know that the intersection of the angle bisectors in a triangle is the incenter so I drew that in too. I also know that from the incenter theorem, the segments from the incenter to the sides of the triangle are equidistant, so I have to find 4 lengths now. I couldn't move on from there because I got stuck so I asked my teacher and she gave me a hint, which is that x + (36 - x) = 27 and so on for each side if you look at the diagram. I don't know how that would be helpful to me though. What I was thinking is that the Angle Bisector Proportionality Theorem comes into play here somehow but I don't know how to apply it. There's a lot of spatial thinking here and that's something I'm not good at lol. Can someone walk me through this or give me a few hints please?

Comment: That diagram looks like nonsense, if it accurately reflects/is reflected by statements like "$x+(36-x)=27$".

Comment: The angle bisector proportionality theorem is exactly what you're looking for. It says for instance that AB/AF = CB/CF and you know what lengths AB and CB are! But before you start, you need to make sure that all your sides are labeled correctly. $x+(36-x) = 36$.

Comment: Using angle bisector proportionality rule you can mark segments as $27x$, $36x$, $27y$, $42y$, $36z$, $42z$, such that $27x+36x=42$, $27y+42y=36$, $36z+42z=27$.